# Fluctuated Traffic in Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, impressions, clicks

I was checking Google Webmaster Tools and I noticed that the traffic and impressions for some pages in my site are very fluctuated from High to ZERO as shown in the screenshot below. Any idea what might be the reason(s)/wrong behind this. by the way, this applies to too many pages with completely different content.

[image]

While Google Analytics shows completely different graph for the same link
[image]